# Call the method of MainViewController from inside ViewController didselectrowatindexpath Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

`

```
"BeneficieryListViewController.h"
    @protocol BeneficieryListViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)shiftTabLocation:(CGFloat)tabValue;
    @end

    @interface BeneficieriesListViewController : UIViewController
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id<BeneficieryListViewControllerDelegate> myDelegate;
    @end

"BeneficieryListViewController.m"
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(self.myDelegate && [self.myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shiftTabLocation:)])
        {
            [self.myDelegate shiftTabLocation:2.0];
        }
  }
"MainViewController.m"      
    -(void)shiftTabLocation:(CGFloat)tabValue
    {
        BeneficieriesListViewController *bvc = [[BeneficieriesListViewController alloc] init];
        bvc.myDelegate = self;

        [self selectTabAtIndex:tabValue didSwipe:YES];
    }
```

`I have to create horizontal scrollable UIViewControllers contains 4 tabs and on the selection of each tab different UIView should be shown. For this, I am using library and created one UIViewController as a subclass of that library "ViewPagerController". And, I created one NSMutableArray which contains 4 UIViewControllers which I am passing as UIView on each selection of the tab.

One UIViewController has UITableView, What I have to do now is - on the selection of UITableViewCell (inside 1st UIViewController) the tab bar should change its position and shift to another tab acc to the condition.

I have tried using delegate to call the method of Main View Controller but its not working and I also tried with directly specifying the object of the Main View Controller and calling its method but its not working.

Kindly help me to solve this issue, I am stuck in this from many days.
Thanks in advance to review the questions.

Comment: Please show the code of tableview, delegate and delegate listener in the main class.

Comment: yea i updated it along with code.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the delegate of BeneficieriesListViewController in the function BeneficieriesListViewController, which is called by the delegate. Therefore it is not working. Move the following code in MainViewController to viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method

MainViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

BeneficieriesListViewController *bvc = [[BeneficieriesListViewController alloc] init];
    bvc.myDelegate = self;
}
```

and it will work. Now the shiftTabLocation function will be like this

```
-(void)shiftTabLocation:(CGFloat)tabValue
{
    [self selectTabAtIndex:tabValue didSwipe:YES];
}
```

Comment: i have created delegate method in BeneficieryListViewController.h and calling it in MainViewController.

Comment: Did that but still not working , not calling delegate method.

Comment: try without using if condition and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks #Fawad , i tried the same way, but still not working. Actually that MainViewController Class is a subclass of ViewPagerController , is that the issue that its not calling the delegate method ?

Comment: @ReetaChainani If ViewPagerController is a subclass of UIViewController, it should work. I have tested the code and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I cant get what happens in the shiftTabLocation method. For what reason you create unused BeneficieriesListViewController object here?

Is the delegate object exists at the moment you call BeneficieryListViewControllerDelegate methods?

If so you faces one of two cases:

1. the method being called as it was expected
2. app crashes because delegate object class doesn't implement this delegate method

In case delegate property is nil at the moment you call it, try to find where you have created BeneficieriesListViewController object and its delegate property. Don't forget your delegate property is weak and it deallocates at the moment it loses the last strong link.

Comment: Thanks for review the code. Actually, the issue is, its not calling the delegate method, i mean its not going inside the if condition (in BeneficieryListViewController.m) i dont know why its happening. I have worked with delegate earlier which is wokring fine and i did the same with this VC also but its not going inside in if condition .